Work Done and Direction with frictional forces
This might be a dumb question, but if work done is equal to the force exerted on an object in the  direction of motion (so W = F*S), then how come frictional forces do work on an object.
For example,  in the picture below, if the object is moving on a rough horizontal plane and friction is acting on the object in the completely opposite direction to motion, then how is work being done (especially since negative work cannot be done as work is a scalar quantity).   

"Especially since negative work cannot be done as work is a scalar quantity" You may misunderstand what's a scalar. A scalar could be negative depending on how we define it.

so does negative work done not represent the direction in which the work is done, but instead that the energy is being transferred away from the object (as an example)?

@WhoAmIWhyAmIHere Exactly. The sign convention used to define work as positive or negative serves only to relate that energy is being transferred way from or to a specificaly defined physical system.

Power and Work can be negative.

Definition of power and work. The definition of the power of a force $\mathbf{F}$ ancting on a point moving with velocity $\mathbf{v}$ is
$$P := \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v} \ .$$
It's work while the system evolves from point $\mathbf{r}_0$ to point $\mathbf{r}_1$ along the path $\gamma$ is defined as
$$W = \int_{\gamma} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = \int_{\gamma} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v} \,  dt  = \int_{\gamma} P \, dt \ ,$$
having written the elementary displacement as the product of the velocity and the elementary time interval, $d \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{v} d t$.
Remark: power of a force can be negative. Being the scalar product of two vector quantities, power is negative if the angle between these two vectors is larger than $\pi/2$ (and in 2D problems $\theta \in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\pi]$), so that $\cos \theta < 0$. Work can be negative has well, being the integral of a function that can be negative.
Power of dynamic friction. The total power of dynamic friction exchanged between two parts of a system is always negative, and it dissipates mechanical energy into heat. Being the power always negative, the work is negative as well.
As suggested by Dale in his comment, if friction acts as an external force on the system, it can have add positive power to the system. See the end of the answer for a discussion of two bodies in relative motion.
Focusing on the motion of a body sliding on a wall at rest, the dynamic friction force is always opposite w.r.t. the velocity of the body. With some math, if the velocity of the body is $\mathbf{v} = v \mathbf{\hat{x}}$, the dynamic friction can be modeled as $\mathbf{F}^d = - f^d N \frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|} = -f^d N \, \text{sgn}(v)\mathbf{\hat{x}}$, with $f^d$ dynamic friction coefficient and $N\ge0$ normal reaction from the wall.
From the definition of the power of a force, $P = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v}$, the power of the friction force reads
$$P^d = \mathbf{F}^d \cdot \mathbf{v} = - f^d N \frac{\mathbf{v}}{|\mathbf{v}|} \cdot \mathbf{v} = - f^d N |\mathbf{v}| \le 0 \ .$$
Edit, following Dale's comment. Friction between two bodies in relative motion. Let's consider here an example of two bodies in relative motion w.r.t. an inertial observer, sliding one over the other on an interface with dynamical friction coefficient $f^d$. Let body $1$ and body $2$ move with velocity $\mathbf{v}_1 = v_1 \mathbf{\hat{x}}$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ w.r.t. the inertial observer. Let $N$ the norm of the normal component of the force exchanged and $\mathbf{F}^d_{12}$ the dynamical friction acting on body $1$ due to the friction with body $2$, and $\mathbf{F}^d_{21}$ the force acting on $2$ due to $1$.
Force $\mathbf{F}^d_{12}$ is opposite w.r.t. the relative velocity $\mathbf{v}_{1/2} := \mathbf{v}_1 - \mathbf{v}_2 = - (\mathbf{v}_2 - \mathbf{v}_1) = - \mathbf{v}_{2/1}$,
$$\mathbf{F}^d_{12} = - f^d N \frac{\mathbf{v}_{1/2}}{|\mathbf{v}_{1/2}|} = - \mathbf{F}^{d}_{21} \ .$$
While the power of friction acting on the individual bodies could be either positive or negative,
$$P^{d}_1 = \mathbf{F}^d_{12} \cdot \mathbf{v}_1 = - f^d N \frac{\mathbf{v}_{1/2}}{|\mathbf{v}_{1/2}|} \cdot \mathbf{v}_1$$
$$P^{d}_2 = \mathbf{F}^d_{21} \cdot \mathbf{v}_2 = f^d N \frac{\mathbf{v}_{1/2}}{|\mathbf{v}_{1/2}|} \cdot \mathbf{v}_2 \ ,$$
the total power $P^d = P^d_1 + P^d_2$ is always negative,
$$P^d = - f^d N \frac{\mathbf{v}_{1/2}}{|\mathbf{v}_{1/2}|} \cdot (\mathbf{v}_1 - \mathbf{v}_2) = - f^d N |\mathbf{v}_{1/2}| < 0 \ .$$

Very good answer +1. One small nitpick: the power of dynamic friction can be positive. Consider for example the dynamic friction between a fast-moving moving conveyor belt and an object initially at rest being placed on the conveyor belt. Or an object sliding from the front to the back of the bed of an accelerating truck.

Yeah, your right. I messed up with editing. I originally wrote the "always negative" sentence in the part starting with "Focusing on the motion ...on a wall at rest". I'm moving that part back to the original location.
It should be ok there, but it's better if you double-check as well

otherwise, we need to extend the analysis to the overall system, belt+object in your example, and consider the relative motion. In this closed system, the overall power of friction force is negative. But this point could make the answer difficult to read. I'll make an edit with your example at the end of the answer

Good and complete edits! Nice also that is shows that the total mechanical power lost depends on the relative velocity, but not the reference frame. I hope others vote this up because it deserves more than just my +1
